# Change the bitmap via x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I try to modify the bitmap - add a pixel on it.

```
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp

put_pixel:
mov eax, DWORD [ebp+8]  ;address of bitmap
add eax, 130            ;take address i wanna change
mov eax, [eax]          ;load address
not eax                 ;this adders is ff(white) change to (00) black
mov ecx, eax    ;return value
mov eax, ecx        ;return ecx
pop ebp
ret
```

But it does not do a thing. Is it a proper way of changing the pixel color on the bitmap? Maybe should I save it somehow?

Comment: You read the pixel color, now what? Where do you write a new color?

Comment: I try to modify it with not eax.

Comment: This changes the register, not the value in memory.

Comment: Ok, so something like: mov [eax], 0 ? But it does not compile when I do it like this, so i guess it is wrong.

Comment: Something like this. But you need to store the address somewhere, since you currently overwrite your address in `eax` with the data you read.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `mov eax, [esp+4]` / `not dword [eax+130]` / `ret`.  Or maybe `not byte [eax+130]`, because you talk about changing black (ff) to white, not `00ffffff` RGBA.  You need a size specifier if there's no register operand, otherwise the assembler doesn't know whether you want byte/word/dword/qword operand-size.

Comment: `mov eax, DWORD [ebp+8]`  ;address of bitmap
`add eax, 130`            ;take address i wanna change
`mov [eax], 0`          ;load value on addres
 
I do it this way right now but i get an error.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have tried `not dword [eax+130]` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Then you have the wrong address in EAX when that instruction runs.  Try looking at C compiler output for a C function that does what you want.  e.g. on https://godbolt.org/

Comment: When I check the address I always get the value saved on it so the address on EAX seems to be good.

Comment: Why are you putting the `put_pixel` label in the middle of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I write it as an answer.
You are replacing the address in `EAX` with the value at its address with this instruction:

```
mov eax, [eax]           ;load address
```

Here you overwrite the address that you'd need to write-back the updated value. So change your code to

```
put_pixel:               ;moved before the frame creation
push ebp                 ;create the frame
mov  ebp, esp            ;...
mov  edx, DWORD [ebp+8]  ;address of bitmap
add  edx, 130            ;calculate address of pixel you want to change
mov  eax, DWORD [edx]    ;load value at address
not  eax                 ;this adders is ff(white) change to (00) black
mov  DWORD [edx], eax    ;write-back updated pixel value
                         ;pixel value is still in EAX as return value
pop ebp                  ;restore frame
ret
```

One problem remains:
130 is not a multiple of 4. So, if you have a 4-bytes-per-Pixel-Situation, you're going to modify the value of (at least) two pixels (unless there is some kind of header the question doesn't tell us about). Rethink that aspect, so that you can modify only *exactly one pixel*.

**EDIT:**
I incorporated the critique by @Michael Petch and set the entry label before the frame creation to get a full sample. Thanks.